# Virtual products Login Restriction. Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, login, virtual-products

I have enabled guest checkout, i need if virtual products available in cart login mandatory, how can i set the condition like if virtual products available in cart login mandatory.

Comment: @AsadKhan Actually mine case virtual products, and may i know where you adding the condition?

Comment: @AsadKhan Let me ask one question, its just my idea i don't know whether its possible or not. If click virtual product add-to-cart button shall we add script to add-to-cart button function and check the condition like virtual products need sign-in, if not sign-in virtual products not able to add add-to-cart, and make sure one thing, only for selected id based products, rest of the virtual products purchase as a guest customer. Make me a pardon if i wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think if you want to download Virtual Products without Logging In then you have to make such a condition in which when customer want to buy anything virtual then randomly a random user (your created) will be logged In.. then it will be easily possible.. (it is just my guess may occer many errors or maybe not possible this scenarion)